# Buffer error sklearn SVM toolkit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this thing. I'm picking up some data from a text file and making a list like this

```
d3list=[]
d4list=[]
for i in range (0,99):
    d3list.append(data3[i,:])
for i in range (0,99):
    d4list.append(data4[i,:])

X = [d3list,d4list]
y = [0,1]
msv = svm.SVC()
msv.fit(X,y)
```

But when I try to run this I got this error

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 2, got 3)
```

I don't know if it's wrong on X part or on Y part. As far as I know a list of list is admitted as an input for the X part.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposedly, your `d3list` and `d4list` contains list of numpy arrays. You should have a 1-d vector of numbers, not list of lists.

The following works fine in my machine.

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

data3 = np.random.rand(100,2)
data4 = np.random.rand(100,2)

d3list=[]
d4list=[]

for i in range (0,99):
    d3list += list(data3[i,:]) #d3list is the concatenation
for i in range (0,99):
    d4list += list(data4[i,:]) #d4list is the concatenation

X = [d3list,d4list]
y = [0,1]
msv = svm.SVC()
msv.fit(X,y)
```

To elaborate,

```
>>> myList = []
>>> myList.append([1,2,3])
>>> myList.append([4,5,6])
>>> myList
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> myList = []
>>> myList += [1,2,3]
>>> myList += [4,5,6]
>>> myList
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Ok I get it somehow but the thing is this. data3 or data4 are like this

    data3=[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]

Comment: @JesusRincon SVM, by its nature, needs a 1D vector.

Comment: So it's actually imposible to make an input like this? Any other way to do it?

Comment: Actually this worked, but my problem wasn't X. It was y. y must be 100 zeroes followed by 100 ones. Thanks a lot for the help